# Checking not null argument in predefined JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

There is a predefined JavaScript function that sets a grid cell style conditionally. This function checks only the equality condition whether the 4th argument is equal to 3rd argument then sets the style of the 1st argument cell. (No access to the function definition).

But my requirement is using this predefined function, I want to check if the 3rd argument is not `null`. So how can I pass not `null` as 4th argument to this predefined function?

```
changeCellStyle(celltobeStyled, { 'background-color': 'Orange' }, celltoCompare, Comparewithvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some wrapper:

```
function wrapper(a,b,c,d) {
    if (d == null) return;
    return changeCellStyle(a, b, c, d);
}
```

or with default value:

```
function wrapper(a,b,c,d) {
        return d == null ? changeCellStyle(a, b, c, 'default value') : changeCellStyle(a, b, c, d)
}
```

Comment: Better `return changeCellStyle(a, b, c, d == null ? 'default value' : d);`

Comment: changeCellStyle('File Number', { 'background-color':'Orange'}, 'Ref #', not null); the suggestions didn't work for me.     in this function call, value of the cell is referred by 'Ref #' but not any variable. I can't get the cell id also through inspect, as it is dynamically referring the cells. I am told zul or Groovy also used in this function.(this info might help)